# Python dictionary from list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to generate a dictionary to count items in a list of lists with conditions. I am trying to get the results as values in a tuple, for example if my initial data is a list of lists like this:

```
my_list = [[(1,2),5],[(1,2),9],[(2,3),0],[(2,3),2],[(1,2),5],[(1,2),9],[(2,3),5]]
```

The desired outcome would be a dictionary with key the first element of each lists. The values of the dictionary would be a tuple of two elements, the number of items having that same key (total count) and how many values are 5 for the second item (conditional count).

```
dict_desired = {(1,2):(4,2),(2,3):(3,1)}
```

I did it but in a way that seems not very neat, and i was wondering if someone with more python experience could help me out to build it maybe using comprehensions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Sounds like a good usecase for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter)

Comment: have you tried *anything at all*?

Comment: Your operation is basically a group-by, which is not something that you can implement efficiently using comprehensions (which are for expressing *mapping/filtering* operations, this would require you to re-iterate over the entire thing on each iteration, when you can group in a single, linear pass)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the poster claims to have some code and is therefore entitled to the benefit of the doubt (especially being a new contributor on Stack Overflow) 

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic, efficient way to do this is to use a loop:

```
my_list = [[(1,2),5],[(1,2),9],[(2,3),0],[(2,3),2],[(1,2),5],[(1,2),9],[(2,3),5]]
result = {}
empty = 0, 0

for key, value in my_list:
    count, fives = result.get(key, empty)
    result[key] = (count + 1, fives + (value == 5))
```

To do this using comprehensions, you require going over the list on each iteration, something like:

```
result = {
    key:(
        sum(k == key for k,_ in my_list),
        sum(v == 5 for k,v in my_list if k == key)
    ) for key, value in my_list
}
```

Which is very unpythonic and inefficient. You can maybe try to make a set out of the keys first, but it still won't be as efficient as the regular for-loop, and perhaps there is some hacky way with assignment expressions to make it work efficiently, but it certainly won't be *neater*.

So, you have a nice, readable, linear-time for-loop versus a convoluted, unreadable, quadratic time dictionary comprehension. The choice is clear, IMO.